# How to convert SQL UPDATE query to PySpark (tables to dataframes)

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sql-update

I have this `UPDATE` SQL query that I need to convert to PySpark to work with dataframes. I'd like to know if it's possible to do it with dataframes and how to do it.

The SQL query:

```sql
UPDATE TBL1
SET COL_C=1
FROM TBL1
INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.COL_A=TBL2.COL_A AND TBL1.COL_B=TBL2.COL_B
INNER JOIN TBL3 ON TBL2.COL_A=TBL3.COL_A AND TBL2.COL_B=TBL3.COL_B
```

```
    df_TBL1=TBL1
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M| 3000|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M| 4000|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F| 1000|
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
    df_TBL2=TBL2
+-------+---------+----------+------+-----+
|  COL_A|    COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|
+-------+---------+----------+------+-----+
|   John|     Snow|1791-04-01|     M| 9000|
|Michael|     Rose|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|
| Robert|Baratheon|1778-09-05|     M| 9500|
|  Maria|    Jones|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|
+-------+---------+----------+------+-----+
    df_TBL3=TBL3 
+--------+------+----------+------+-----+
|   COL_A| COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|
+--------+------+----------+------+-----+
| Michael|  Rose|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|
|   Peter|Parker|1978-09-05|     M| 4000|
|   Maria| Jones|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|
|MaryJane| Brown|1980-12-17|     F|10000|
+--------+------+----------+------+-----+
```

The joins give me:

```py
df_TBL_ALL=df_TBL1 \
.join(df_TBL2,(df_TBL1.COL_A==df_TBL2.COL_A) & (df_TBL1.COL_B==df_TBL2.COL_B),how="inner") \
.join(df_TBL3,(df_TBL2.COL_A==df_TBL3.COL_A) & (df_TBL2.COL_B==df_TBL3.COL_B),how="inner") \
.select(df_TBL1["*"]) \
.withColumn("COL_C",spf.lit(1))
```

And then, I'm trying to join them

```py
df_TBL1_JOINED=df_TBL1 \
.join(df_TBL_ALL,(df_TBL1.COL_A==df_TBL_ALL.COL_A) & (df_TBL1.COL_B==df_TBL_ALL.COL_B),how="left") \
.select(df_TBL1["*"], \
        spf.coalesce(df_TBL_ALL.COL_C,df_TBL1.COL_C).alias("COL_C"))

df_TBL1_JOINED.show()
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+-----+
# |  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|COL_C|
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+-----+
# |  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M| 3000| 3000|
# |    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F| 1000| 1000|
# |  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|    1|
# |Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|    1|
# | Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M| 4000| 4000|
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+-----+
```

But I'm confused about how to go on.

I did:

```py
TBL01_R=TBL01_R \
.drop("COL_C")

TBL01_R=TBL01_R \
.withColumnRenamed("COL_Nova","COL_C").show()

TBL01=TBL01_R

# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
# |  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
# |  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M| 3000|
# |    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F| 1000|
# |  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|    1|
# |Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|    1|
# | Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M| 4000|
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
```

I got to the expected result but I don't know if it is the best performing way to achieve it.

Expected result: df_tbl1 with COL_C updated with a 1 in all rows present in the join of df_tbl1 with df_tbl2 and df_tbl3.

```
df_TBL1:

+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M| 3000|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|    1|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M| 4000|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|    1|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F| 1000|
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do a concise and performant option. The following does just 2 necessary joins avoiding the last inner join which you used in your question.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

updating = F.forall(F.array('t2', 't3'), lambda x: x)
df_TBL1 = (
    df_TBL1.withColumnRenamed('COL_C', 'COL_C_old').alias('T1')
    .join(df_TBL2.withColumn('t2', F.lit(True)), ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], 'left')
    .join(df_TBL3.withColumn('t3', F.lit(True)), ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], 'left')
    .withColumn('updated_c', F.when(updating, 1).otherwise(F.col('COL_C_old')))
    .select('T1.*', F.col('updated_c').alias('COL_C'))
    .drop('COL_C_old')
)
```

```py
df_TBL1.show()
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
# |  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
# |  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M| 3000|
# |    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F| 1000|
# |  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|    1|
# |Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|    1|
# | Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M| 4000|
# +-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
```

---

**How the update works, line-by-line**

First, you join the 3 tables together based on COL_A and COL_B. But all with slight modifications: df_TBL1 has renamed COL_C and added an alias 'T1' (another name for better accessing the table); df_TBL2 and df_TBL3 each have one additional column 't2' and 't3' respectively, which always is True (after joining, they will indicate that those rows exist in those tables).

```py
.withColumnRenamed('COL_C', 'COL_C_old').alias('T1')
```

```
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C_old|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M|     3000|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|     4000|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M|     4000|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|     4000|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F|     1000|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+
```

```py
.join(df_TBL2.withColumn('t2', F.lit(True)), ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], 'left')
```

```
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C_old|       dob|gender|COL_C|  t2|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M|     3000|      null|  null| null|null|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F|     1000|      null|  null| null|null|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|     4000|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|true|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|     4000|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|true|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M|     4000|      null|  null| null|null|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+
```

```py
.join(df_TBL3.withColumn('t3', F.lit(True)), ['COL_A', 'COL_B'], 'left')
```

```
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+----------+------+-----+----+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C_old|       dob|gender|COL_C|  t2|       dob|gender|COL_C|  t3|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+----------+------+-----+----+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M|     3000|      null|  null| null|null|      null|  null| null|null|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F|     1000|      null|  null| null|null|      null|  null| null|null|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|     4000|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|true|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|true|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|     4000|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|true|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|true|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M|     4000|      null|  null| null|null|      null|  null| null|null|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+----------+------+-----+----+
```

After the join, you have `withColumn` which creates one additional column named 'updated_c': if you have True in BOTH 't2' and 't3' columns, you write 1 in 'updated_c', otherwise you take the value from 'COL_C_old'. `forall` does the check in the array if ALL its values conform to the lambda function. The array is created using function `array` from columns 't2' and 't3'. `lambda x: x` just checks if the value is True (if row existed in df_TBL2 or df_TBL3, values would be True, if not, they would be null - we need only True).

```py
updating = F.forall(F.array('t2', 't3'), lambda x: x)
.withColumn('updated_c', F.when(updating, 1).otherwise(F.col('COL_C_old')))
```

```
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+----------+------+-----+----+---------+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C_old|       dob|gender|COL_C|  t2|       dob|gender|COL_C|  t3|updated_c|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+----------+------+-----+----+---------+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M|     3000|      null|  null| null|null|      null|  null| null|null|     3000|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F|     1000|      null|  null| null|null|      null|  null| null|null|     1000|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|     4000|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|true|1967-12-01|     F| 4000|true|        1|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|     4000|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|true|2000-05-19|     M| 4000|true|        1|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M|     4000|      null|  null| null|null|      null|  null| null|null|     4000|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+----------+------+-----+----+----------+------+-----+----+---------+
```

Then you `select` all the columns from df_TBL1 using its alias name `'T1.*'` (it also takes 'COL_C_old'), and add one more column: 'updated_c', renaming it to 'COL_C'.

```py
.select('T1.*', F.col('updated_c').alias('COL_C'))
```

```
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+-----+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C_old|COL_C|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+-----+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M|     3000| 3000|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F|     1000| 1000|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|     4000|    1|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|     4000|    1|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M|     4000| 4000|
+-------+--------+----------+------+---------+-----+
```

Finally, `drop` unnecessary 'COL_C_old'.

```py
.drop('COL_C_old')
```

```
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
|  COL_A|   COL_B|       dob|gender|COL_C|
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
|  James|   Smith|1991-04-01|     M| 3000|
|    Jen|   Brown|1980-02-17|     F| 1000|
|  Maria|   Jones|1967-12-01|     F|    1|
|Michael|    Rose|2000-05-19|     M|    1|
| Robert|Williams|1978-09-05|     M| 4000|
+-------+--------+----------+------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks @ZygD for your answer! Is not clear for me how the function updating is working, could you please explian? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user9910379 - I have added a more descriptive line-by-line explanation with resulting dataframes.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it easily using temptable and dataframe in spark sql. temp table are also entity of spark-sql , so it is same as dataframe

```
>>> TBL1.show()
+-----+--------+--------+
|COL_A|   COL_B|   COL_C|
+-----+--------+--------+
|    A|       B|  scjsdk|
|   A1|cnddssac|saacjsdk|
|    A|   cndds|  scjsdk|
+-----+--------+--------+

>>> TBL2.show()
+-----+-----------+----------+
|COL_A|      COL_B|     COL_C|
+-----+-----------+----------+
|    A|          B|   scjksdk|
|   A1|cndmmkdssac|sbkaacjsdk|
|    A|      cndds| scjjbjsdk|
+-----+-----------+----------+

>>> TBL3.show()
+-----+-----------+------------+
|COL_A|      COL_B|       COL_C|
+-----+-----------+------------+
|    A|          B|  scjcjbksdk|
|   A1|cndmmkdssac|sbkadaacjsdk|
|    A|      cndds|scjjdwfbjsdk|
+-----+-----------+------------+

>>> TBL1.registerTempTable("TBL1")
>>> TBL2.registerTempTable("TBL2")
>>> TBL3.registerTempTable("TBL3")

>>> final_df=spark.sql("select * FROM TBL1 INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.COL_A=TBL2.COL_A AND TBL1.COL_B=TBL2.COL_B INNER JOIN TBL3 ON TBL2.COL_A=TBL3.COL_A AND TBL2.COL_B=TBL3.COL_B")
>>> final_df.show()
+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+------------+
|COL_A|COL_B| COL_C|COL_A|COL_B|    COL_C|COL_A|COL_B|       COL_C|
+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+------------+
|    A|    B|scjsdk|    A|    B|  scjksdk|    A|    B|  scjcjbksdk|
|    A|cndds|scjsdk|    A|cndds|scjjbjsdk|    A|cndds|scjjdwfbjsdk|
+-----+-----+------+-----+-----+---------+-----+-----+------------+
```

***************  Update COL_C *******************

```
>>> final_df.withColumn("COL_C",lit(1)).show()
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|COL_A|COL_B|COL_C|COL_A|COL_B|COL_C|COL_A|COL_B|COL_C|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|    B|    1|    A|    B|    1|    A|    B|    1|
|    A|cndds|    1|    A|cndds|    1|    A|cndds|    1|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

======= OR IF you want to Update only TBL1 COL_C value only =====================

```
>>> final_df=spark.sql("select TBL1.COL_A,TBL1.COL_B,TBL1.COL_C FROM TBL1 INNER JOIN TBL2 ON TBL1.COL_A=TBL2.COL_A AND TBL1.COL_B=TBL2.COL_B INNER JOIN TBL3 ON TBL2.COL
>>> final_df.show()
+-----+-----+------+
|COL_A|COL_B| COL_C|
+-----+-----+------+
|    A|    B|scjsdk|
|    A|cndds|scjsdk|
+-----+-----+------+
```

************  Update COL_C *****************

```
>>> final_df.withColumn("COL_C",lit(1)).show()
+-----+-----+-----+
|COL_A|COL_B|COL_C|
+-----+-----+-----+
|    A|    B|    1|
|    A|cndds|    1|
+-----+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @sachin-tiwari , worked just fine, actually my spected result is df_tbl1 with COL_C updated with a 1 in all rows present in the join of df_tbl1 with df_tbl2 and df_tbl3. (Just edited cause it was not clear in my first post). Maybe it can be done using another join?